# How to Access File Contents in VS Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to scan through the contents of the file currently open in the workspace. I tried:

```js
console.log(vscode.window.activeTextEditor); // Doesn't work
```

I also tried:

```js
vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(vscode.window.terminals).then(document => {
  let text = document.getText();
  console.log(text);
});
```

That last one threw an error: "did not find a valid project structure, exiting...." What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please consider checking out the [VS Code Extension Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/) and in particular the [Document Editing Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/document-editing-sample). It does show how to read the text in the currently active document in the editor.

To read text in the currently active document editor, put this code into your `extension.ts`:

```js
'use strict';

import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.scanDocument', function () {
        // Get the active text editor
        const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;

        if (editor) {
            let document = editor.document;

            // Get the document text
            const documentText = document.getText();

            // DO SOMETHING WITH `documentText`
        }
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
```

And declare this command in your `package.json`:

```json
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "extension.scanDocument",
                "title": "Scan current document..."
            }
        ]
    }
```

... run the extension, open a file and invoke the command from the command pallet.